# how to run a java class in another folder with jar file

Tags: java, path

i'd like to run a java class on other folder, i have a mysqlcon.jar on the current path and a PetsGUI.class on ./classes/

when i try to run it by doing

```
java -cp .:mysqlcon.jar -d classes/PetsGUI
```

i receive

```
classes/PetsGUI not found
```

if i move mysqlcon.jar on classes and type

```
java -cp .:mysqlcon.jar PetsGUI
```

on classes/ it runs, so the code is correct. what's the correct command to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need the jar file, and the classes directory in the classpath:

```
java -cp ./classes:mysqlcon.jar PetsGUI
```

java doesn't expect a file path as argument. It expects the fully quelified name of a class. And that class is then searched on the classpath.